# R CMD check error : how to get rid of hidden files and directory in devel R package on windows?

Tags: r, windows, cmd, rstudio

I am building my R package on Rstudio, and I am running R CMD check for my packages. However, R CMD check warn few issues that possibly result in error. I checked my project home directory, indeed some files was hidden, now I set them up visible. Just out of curiosity, how to stop exist `.gitignore, .Rproj.user, .git` in my package directory ? R CMD check complain about these, because these files are not properties of packages, and also not being R package structure convention. How can I get rid of these warning in my Packages ? I tried to create dummy packages on my machine, but these properties always show up in package home directory, why this is happen when building R package with Rstudio ? How can I fix this CMD check error ? Any idea please ?

According to writing R Extension manual, R package structure supposed to be :

```
myPackage
 `- inst
     `- extdata
             `- data1.csv
             `- data2.csv
 `- R
    `- ...
 `- NAMESPACE
 `- man
     `-hello.Rd
 `- DESCRIPTION
```

- Note :

This is session of R CMD check, part of error message as follow :

Found the following executable files:
      .git/objects/00/bc868b99806415c87749e4a2e060f99eb811da
      .git/objects/01/10cc76aa5573ca9401e72b36ad3672b39f23cb
      .git/objects/01/5c9910f52a0560426a1b00e1e31e1f060afdfb
      .git/objects/03/0ca1ef161838ebeb6a225f354a6a8eec95e472
      ....
      ...

```
  .git/objects/fd/6439dfc6532e7e3a76e76b3e4ca4fd683b2c5e
  .git/objects/fd/ebc184b447002ee6239231093eb026b9bb3aec
  .git/objects/fe/02f64dd278d70ff2e5fb212834d131bc23fddb
  .git/objects/ff/15763b397945d0ee2e2523eab1bfd460f84529
  .git/objects/ff/5413a4dc5f2710fe30ad14f4eb10992ad5aee4
  .git/objects/ff/b8e86c018008d3cee09871f76df3a7277cb1c7
Source packages should not contain undeclared executable files.
See section 'Package structure' in the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.
* checking for hidden files and directories ... NOTE
Found the following hidden files and directories:
  .gitignore
  .Rproj.user
  .git
These were most likely included in error. See section 'Package
structure' in the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.
```

inst/ must be created in my package home directory, but I don't have this property when I am building my packages. Why I missed this directory ? Can any one point me how to possibly solve this problem ? How can I fix this CMD check error ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are (likely) doing it wrong.  Do the following:

```
cd ..
R CMD build yourDirectory/
R CMD check yourPackage_0.1.0.tar.gz
```

as the *creation* of the source tarball will *automatically exclude* the internal directories you want skipped.  Which is why checking against tarballs (rather than directories) is the *recommended and documented* approach.

Note that in RStudio the option in the Build tag is called 'Check' and does just that:  create a tarball first (after possibly running roxygen or other steps as configured) and then checks the tarball for you.  That is as easy as clicking one button, or typing Ctrl-Shift-E (on my platform).

Finer control of additional files to exclude can be obtained via the `.Rbuildignore` file which tells R which other files to skip.  A number of files and directories are already implicitly declared that way, including the git directories.

Comment: I applied your solution, it stripped away that files from myPackage_0.1.0.tar.gz, now I need to commit these changes and push to git , how can I do this ? Any idea please ?

Comment: If you executed the instructions from Dirk correctly, nothing will have changed in your package directory/folder. You can check that. The .tar.gz should be built every time you change something in your package and you want to check it.

Comment: Your "cannot push this to git" make little sense has what I explained to you is something _about your files_ (ie: usage) rather than a _change to the files_.

Comment: What changes? Your package directory has not changed as you mention. You don't need to push an unchanged directory. `R CMD build ...` followed by `R CMD check ....` is being executed outside the package directory.

Comment: Maybe you added it to `.Rbuildignore`?  We _cannot know_ as you did not show reproducible sources.  (And that is already a different question of yours.)  Look at [this package of mine](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppbdt/tree/master/inst/extdata) whose `inst/extdata/*.csv` is _of course_ in the [resulting tarball](https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/RcppBDT_0.2.3.tar.gz).